# UI-router and linking to anchor tags on other pages?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to do a simple cross reference hyperlink, as in "see 'checkboxes' under the 'ui controls' section", which in plain html might be `<a href="uicontrols.html#checkboxes">`

In my ui-router-based app, I am trying to use

`<a href="" ui-sref="elements.uicontrols({'#': 'checkboxes'})">checkboxes</a>`

to go to the state/page `elements.uicontrols` and then the anchor tag on that page.

It doesn't work, and some Googling turned up this: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/pull/1867

Does anyone know a way to accomplish links like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it may be solved your problem. you should use `id` in anchor tag of plain html page to create reference link.

In ui-router-based app

```
<a ui-sref="elements.uicontrols({'#':'checkboxes'})">checkboxes</a>
```

in plain html might be

```
<a id="checkboxes" href="uicontrols.html">check to another page link</a>
```

*N.B:* should have sufficient content bellow the plain `anchor` tag to show that anchor tag at the top.